# C++: passing a string-literal of Type const char* to a string-parameter

Tags: c++, string, const-char

i'm new to c++ and have a lack of understanding why this code works well:

```
string GetString(string promt)
{
    cout << promt << ": ";
    string temp;
    getline(cin, temp); 
    return temp; 
}

int main()
{
    string firstName = GetString("Enter your first name"); 
    string lastName = GetString("Enter your last name");

    cout<< "Your Name is: " << firstName << " " << lastName; 


    cin.ignore(); 
    cin.get(); 

    return 0;
}
```

String-Literals like "bla" are of Type const char*. At least auto i = "bla"; indicates, that i is of Type "const char*". Why is it possible to pass it to the GetString-Function, because the function expects a string and not a const char*?

Comment: String literals are of type `const char(&)[N]`, but since C can't copy an array to the local variable, `auto` makes the local `const char*` anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string` has a [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) which takes a `char const*` and initialised the string with the null terminated string pointed to by the pointer. This constructor is not `explicit`, so it can be used in implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the std::string constructors.
What happens is that compiler found a constructor that accepts your const char* and used it to automatically convrt const char* to std::string.
BTW I would suggest using `const std::string& prompt` instead.